# Facebook XFBML Like button still embedded in iframe

Tags: facebook

I am maybe misunderstanding the facebook documentation for the xfbml.

They say there are two ways of incorporating a like button into a site via iframe or xfbml.

When i use xfbml though the button is still embedded in an iframe.

Whats the difference therefore?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the XFBML like button still creates an iframe. The two versions will end up creating the same result. The only real difference between the two is that with the xfbml version you can subscribe to the "edge.create" event which tells you when somebody clicks the button. You cannot subscribe to this event with the iframe version. Additionally, with the XFBML you can control when it is rendered using the Javascript SDK by calling   FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));